# How to create a new column based on one of three other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that has a movie name column and 3 other columns (let's call them A, B, and C) that are ratings from 3 different sources. 
There are many movies with only one rating, some movies with a combination from the 3 forums, and some with no ratings. I want to create a new column that will:

1. If A column has associated rating, use A.
2. If A column is empty, get associated rating from B.
3. If B column is empty, get associated rating from C.
4. If C column is empty, return "Unrated"

This is what I have in my code so far:

```
def check_rating(rating):
    if newyear['Yahoo Rating'] != "\\N":
        return rating
    else:
        if newyear['Movie Mom Rating'] != "\\N":
            return rating
        else:
            if newyear['Critc Rating'] != "\\N":
                return rating
            else:
                return "Unrated"

df['Rating'] = df.apply(check_rating, axis=1)
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

For visual of my dataframe, here is `newyear.head()`:

[image: newyear dataframe]

I am not sure what this value error means to fix this problem and also if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Please post a small sample of your dataframe (as text, not an image) and the expected output.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
df = df.replace('\\N', np.nan)  # this requires import numpy as np
(df['Yahoo Rating'].fillna(df['Movie Mom Rating']
                   .fillna(df['Critic Rating']
                   .fillna("Unrated"))))
```

The reason that your code doesn't work is that `newyear['Yahoo Rating'] != "\\N"` is a boolean array. What you say here is something like `if [True, False, True, False]:`. That's the source of ambiguity. How do you evaluate such a condition? Would you execute if all of them True or would just one of them be enough?

As [M. Klugerford explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38818720/2285236), you can change it so it is evaluated row by row (therefore returns a single value). However, row by row apply operations are generally slow and pandas has great tools for handling missing data. That's why I am suggesting this.

Comment: Wow this is very useful! Thank you for explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `rating` in your original function .. but `rating` is the **row**, not the value of any column

```
>>> df
    A   B   C Genre Title Year
0   7   6  \N    g1    m1   y1
1  \N   5   7    g2    m2   y2
2  \N  \N  \N    g3    m3   y3
3  \N   4   1    g4    m4   y4
4  \N  \N   3    g5    m5   y5

>>> def rating(row):
    if row['A'] != r'\N':
        return row['A']
    if row['B'] != r'\N':
        return row['B']
    if row['C'] != r'\N':
        return row['C']
    return 'Unrated'

>>> df['Rating'] = df.apply(rating, axis = 1)
>>> df
    A   B   C Genre Title Year   Rating
0   7   6  \N    g1    m1   y1        7
1  \N   5   7    g2    m2   y2        5
2  \N  \N  \N    g3    m3   y3  Unrated
3  \N   4   1    g4    m4   y4        4
4  \N  \N   3    g5    m5   y5        3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't sure how to use def a python function to go from column-row to column-row so this was very helpful.